# read.transaction and association rules Hierarchies single format in R

Tags: python, r

I want to implement the apriori algorithm on the data of a retail store.
My data is as follows. I want to use the hierarchical structure but don't know how?

Can the value of cols be greater than 1 for the apriori algorithm for single format?

Can `cols = (4, 5)` be considered as `cols = (4, 5, 6)`?

```
require(arules)
require(arulesViz)
tab<-read.transactions(file.choose(),header = TRUE,rm.duplicates = FALSE,format="single",sep = 
",",cols=c(4,5))
summary(tab)
rules <-apriori(tab,parameter=list(supp=0.005,conf=0.10,minlen=2))
```

[image]